# Word 2003 XML: Looking for XSL or XSD to render the document in browser

Tags: xml, ms-word, xsd

I've used OpenOffice 3.2 to convert a word doc into Microsoft Word 2003 XML.  I am looking for and XSD or XSL that I can append to the document to show it in my browser.  Can anyone point me in the right direction>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating international standard 2007 XML, instead of 2003. (Use the Novell version of OO)

Then transform to HTML (Microsoft has a stylesheet floating around, or you can use docx4j if java is your cup of tea).

I think you'll get better results displaying an HTML doc, rather than styling OpenXML in the browser (this depends in part on how cross-browser you need to be).

Comment: Taking your suggestion, I did find this tutorial helpful: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=691502&seqNum=5